# Библиотеки для нахождения производных C#

Tags: c#, математика

Подскажите Есть ли библиотеки для нахождения проиводных от функций ?  или как можно реализовать по другом ?

Comment: Руками можно реализовать - это ж просто...

Comment: @Qwertiy в смысле просто? Может автору симаольные вычисления нужны

Comment: @tym32167, так символьные тоже просто. Берём дерево выражения, обходим его и для каждого узла рекурсивно считаем производную. Это ж производная, а не интеграл - с ней всё просто и детерминированно.

Comment: @Qwertiy очевидно, у нас с вами разные представления о простоте :)

Comment: @tym32167, ну просто в switch загнать пачку случаев для текущей вершины типа вот этого: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oas8b.png

Comment: Я был знаком с человеком, который писал и издавал брошюрки с названиями: "Математика - это просто", "Физика - это просто", "Программирование - это просто" и тому подобное.

Comment: @tym32167, не, не ту таблицу, а вот эту: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWCQq.png. И ещё вот эти 2 формулы: (f(x)+g(x))′=f′(x)+g′(x) и (f(x)⋅g(x))′=f′(x)⋅g(x)+f(x)⋅g′(x).

Comment: @Igor, а "С++ для чайников за 3 дня" не издавал?

Comment: @Qwertiy Нет, он застолбил для себя нишу - "[Что угодно] - это просто". И пахал эту нишу не отвлекаясь.

Comment: @Igor А разве с Савватевом что-то случилось? Почему был то? Недавно только был на его лекции)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот одна из самых распространённых: https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics/